# how to implement BottomAppBar in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, material-design

how to implement BottomAppBar in android.

**build.gradle**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
```

**activity_main2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!--    <FrameLayout-->
<!--        android:id="@+id/frames"-->
<!--        android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
<!--        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />-->


    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_app_bar" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

when i start for implement BottomAppBar Then give me this error in xml file:

[image]

when i run app then Force stop app and give this error :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.xxxx.xxxx, PID: 8698
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxxx.xxxx/com.xxxx.xxxx.Activity.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14 in com.xxxx.xxxx:layout/activity_home2: Binary XML file line #14 in com.xxxx.xxxx:layout/activity_home2: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3448)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7807)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1047)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14 in com.xxxx.xxxx:layout/activity_home2: Binary XML file line #14 in com.xxxx.xxxx:layout/activity_home2: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14 in com.xxxx.xxxx:layout/activity_home2: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
```

Comment: 1. Have you tested by running this app?
2. Remove `style` and check again.

Comment: yes, I run the app but force stop and I have to remove style then nothing change.

Comment: Post that crash reports from logs.

Comment: Instead of `1.0.0-beta01`, use `1.2.1`

Comment: @PratikButani add crash report logs in my qus.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error - it's just view cannot be rendered by Android Studio, cause it doesn't know how to load this view. Moreover, you can build your application without any errors.
If you want make preview working - try click `rebuild` in Build settings of Android Studio. It should help to render a preview.

Answer (score 0):

Update your theme of **MaterialComponents**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

The latest version of Material Library is given [here](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#com.google.android.material:material)